# How to position cursor at a particular column (beyond the end of the line)?

Tags: alignment

Given this:

```
2022-07-28 Gå tur med Marvin
motion:rolig                           ...
motion:intens                          .

2022-07-29
motion:rolig                           ...
motion:intens                          ..

2022-08-08
inboxing                               .
folkets:support                        .
some

How to get from here                   to here?
```

how do I come from 'some' on the last line to the column with the periods without manually inserting all the spaces and without using tab characters?

EDIT: How to get the cursor from WORDs on the left to the column of periods on the right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry, I'm finding it difficult to explain my goal. I am simple trying to get from left to right in an effective manner, where right is defined by the column with periods on the other lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `set virtualedit=all` in your vimrc to allow cursor to be
positioned anywhere, even where there are no chars, and then you can use the
normal mode command `80|` to move the cursor to the 80th column and start
typing.

Or, with the cursor on the `.`, you can simply move down one line (with `j`)
and the cursor will remain in the same column.

See `:help virtualedit`

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!